# Error when adding -ObjC to "Other Linker Flags" in my target's Build Settings

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I am trying to use the Twilio API for my Swift project, but I encounter an error when I reach step 4 shown below.

[image]

If I try to add "-ObjC", I am getting the “linker command failed with exit code 1” error.

libTwilioClient.a(TCConnection.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What is causing this issue?

Comment: There should be information in the build log immediately before the "exit code 1" part that shows the real error...missing or duplicate symbols, maybe.  Please add that to your question.

Comment: Edited, it has something to do with bitcode, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to link, open the build settings of your main target and search for bitcode.  Assuming it's now set to "yes" change to "no" and try rebuilding.

If you have source for the library, you can rebuild it with bitcode on instead.